# change which folder to upload to on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to figure out how to change upload directories. I uploaded the project already once. And now I'd like to upload it again, but to a different folder.

I tried different ways, but it seems to be glued to the original folder I uploaded to.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my commit"
git remote add origin <remote repository URL>
git push origin master
```

even if I specify the new repository URL - it still uploads to the original folder ! How can I change this?

Comment: Do you mean "remote repository" when you say "folder"?

Comment: You're only showing commands to set the origin remote once, not changing it. What do you mean by "change upload directory", and what are you doing to try to do that?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can change the remote repo with `git remote set-url origin <new URL>` and then your pushes and fetches will be done with this new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of, "different folder" is a little unclear here, so i will cover a few different possibilities.

**Push to a new branch**
This will push your project to the same repository, but on a separate branch, meaning the first version of the project will be in the same "folder" but still "apart" from each other.

First, create a branch:

```
git branch <branch name>
```

Then, switch to the branch:

```
git switch <branch name>
```

Then, push your project.
You can view all branches of a repository with:

```
git branch
```

**Push to a new repository**
The easiest way to do this is to redirect your remote:

```
git remote set-url <remote name, default: 'origin'> <repository url>
```

Reference:

- [Github: Manage branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository)
- [Github: Manage remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories)